# Trying to printing the dictionary values by taking a list of strings and given user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print the values as a dictionary (like as key and value) with output like `{0: 'Rama', 1: 'Sita', 2: 'Ravana'}`.

Tried Code:

```
def details():
  Stu_Rec = {}
  Names = list()
  print("Enter the Id :\n")
  Id = int(input())
  for i in range(0,Id):
    print("\nEnter the Name ")
    Name = input()
    Names.append(Name)
  for i in range(0,Id):
    for x in Names:
       Stu_Rec[i] = x
  return Stu_Rec

if __name__ == "__main__": 
  Details = details()
  print(Details)**
```

When i am executing the code , the output is mentioned above and below is the snippet

```
~/Python-3$ python details.py
Enter the Id :

3

Enter the Name 
rama

Enter the Name 
sita

Enter the Name 
Ravana
{0: 'Ravana', 1: 'Ravana', 2: 'Ravana'}**
```

Suggest what's wrong with the code I'm trying ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
def details():
Stu_Rec = {}
Names = list()
print("Enter the Id :\n")
Id = int(input())
for i in range(0,Id):
    print("\nEnter the Name ")
    Name = input()
    Names.append(Name)
for i in range(0,Id):
    Stu_Rec[i] = Names[i]
return Stu_Rec

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    Details = details()
    print(Details)
```